# Set value to NULL where both values are 0

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

```
UPDATE `table` SET `repeat_id` = NULL WHERE (`repeat_id` == 0 AND `entry_type` == 0)
```

I'm a little nervous to just try it, I am moderately sure this will do what I want, which is for every row where repeat_id and entry_type are both 0 set the repeat_id to NULL (leaving the entry_type as 0) ...

Have I made any grave mistakes here? Will the code actually do that? I am pretty newbish when it comes to SQL.

Comment: Have you tested it? (On a test system preferably)

Comment: You are confusing single quotes with backticks or double quotes.  I vote to close such questions as a simple typographical error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using quotes, you have to use backticks, and instead of `==` you have to use just one `=`

```
UPDATE `table`
SET
  `repeat_id` = NULL
WHERE
  `repeat_id` = 0 AND `entry_type` = 0
```

anyway, it's always a good idea non to try queries on production databases - try run it first on a developement table, or on a copy of the original table. Eventually you might want to limit the update to a few records:

```
UPDATE `table`
SET
  `repeat_id` = NULL
WHERE
  id in (1,2,3,4)
  and `repeat_id` = 0 AND `entry_type` = 0
```

this will run the query only for records 1,2,3,4 (if you have an id column).

Comment: So far good but I'd wrap the id column in backticks as well as you do it everywhere else.

Answer (score 2):

You just need to get the syntax corrected.

```
UPDATE `table` SET repeat_id = NULL
WHERE repeat_id = 0 AND entry_type = 0
```

Note: `single-quote`s are for constant values. Also, the equality check needs only `=`.

Answer (score 1):

The other two answers address your syntax errors.  This one describes a way to exercise caution on updates.  Start with a select query that has the same where clause as the update query:

```
select *
from table
where repeat_id = 0
and entry_type = 0;
```

Look at the output.  Find something that will allow you to update just one record.

```
update table
set repeat_id = null
where repeat_id = 0
and entry_type = 0
and further filters to restrict update to one record;
```

Run more select queries to check the results of the update.  When you are sufficiently confident, run the original update query.